# Parameter passing between different JavaScript libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, d3.js

In my Application, I have a grid made in extjs, on click of every row I need to pass selected cell values of that row to another JavaScript library. So to do so, I am considering html as a bridge, if I can somehow get the value in html then I think passing rest won't be tough job. In this regard, I have couple of questions

1. Am I correct in the way of my thinking?
2. If so, can anyone suggest me how to pass parameters from extjs to html?

I am retrieving the cell values from Extjs grid using this code

```
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('lineGridChart');
    var selectedRecords= grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
    myWTN  = selectedRecords[0].get('wtn');
    myMOU  = selectedRecords[0].get('avg');
    myWING = selectedRecords[0].get('wing');
    myPDU  = selectedRecords[0].get('pdu');
```

I need to pass those values to d3 or a simple jquery.

Comment: What you are asking seems simple (you just call the library) maybe some example code would help us understand the problem.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What libraries? Post some code. I'd consider HTML as a bridge as a last chance. There should be some exposed interfaces of those libs.

Comment: What is the other library? Why do you want to use html? You have javascript - use it!

Comment: @Hogan, Marcell , Marlo I have edited my question little bit. Kindly have a look

Comment: @abhijit I think you've thought yourself into a corner. The main reason you'd want to avoid calling the other library directly is to keep components encapsulated (and so keep you code maintainable), but you can do that by using events to mediate between components, e.g. on your grid you emit a "row.click" event and monitor that from a piece of code that decides how to handle it.

Comment: @RichardMarr I am also thinking of the same thing (i have put myself into the corner). Anyways thanks for the idea, and the example sounds great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localstorage...
Or just:

```
myData  = selectedRecords[0].getData();
```

Update:

```
myData = {
    data: {},
    set: function(data) {
        myData.data = data;
        // You jquery logik
    }
};

myData.set(selectedRecords[0].getData());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you tell me how i can access this myData in jquery, as i guess myData is currently global in extjs context.

Comment: myData is a global variable in window context. You can use it in jquery.

Comment: yes, rightly myData is global in window context. And i can easily retrieve the value using jquery. But then how the jquery will get the information that the variable value is changed. So i am using Ext.get('IDName') for getting the id and then set(), update() for updating the variable. But unfortunately by doing so the dom thing is getting destroyed and hence the whole space is getting blank.

Comment: @abhijit You can create myData as a object, and describe the required logic by changing it. I was add example in my answer.